# Spring Boot ElasticSearch Port

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-boot, port

I just wrote a small Spring Boot application with ElasticSearch.
Worked very well so far.

What's not working is the REST endpoint of ElasticSearch itself.
I just want it be open to play a little bit with it.
What's the trick here?

Update 5/26/2015:

Elasticsearch version is 1.3.2.

My main() class:
Code works and no error message. 
But as I said, the REST API of ElasticSearch is not available. No open port listed at netstat:

```html
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class SmartSearchRunner  implements CommandLineRunner{

   @Autowired
   private AddressService addressService;

   @Override
   public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
      System.out.println("Hello Spring Boot ElasticSearch!");

      Address ingo = new Address();
      ingo.setId("foo");
      ingo.setName("ingo");

      addressService.addAddress(ingo);

      System.out.println(addressService.getByName("ingo"));
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(SmartSearchRunner.class, args);
   }
}
```

Comment: you should add your code and corresponding error messages

Comment: adding your ElasticSearch version would help as well

Comment: did u check your elastic search config file for 
**http.enabled=true**
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/modules-http.html

Answer (score 5):

Put this in your Spring boot application properties:

spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.http.enabled=true